# How break page numbering and restart it by the last automatically?

Tags: formatting, page-numbering, counters, setcounter, programming-tools

When I write a document it is usual I divide it into more part: so, I am usual to not number part page as into the example put below where I put a document with three parts, like Overture, Part I and Part II.  So as you can observe I restore number page using a set counter where I indicated manually the last value of last numbered page; however, it is common anytime I have to add something to any part during the writing so that I have more times manually update the setcounter page value: is it possibile do this automatically? could someone help me, please?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\quad

\part*{Overture}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Overture}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\quad

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\chapter{Chapter 0}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\quad

\part*{Part I}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part I}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\quad

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{4}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\chapter{Chapter 3}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\quad

\part*{Part II}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part II}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\quad

\chapter{Chapter 4}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{7}

\chapter{Chapter 5}

\chapter{Chapter 6}

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you want an empty page use \thispagestyle{empty} or some other suitable page style and not \pagenumbering{gobble}. (if you look into the log you will see lots of warnings about duplicate destinations because of this).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Putting the command \thispagestyle{\empty} and deleting the command \pagenumbmering{gobble} then the part page is numbered and I do not want this.

Comment: If you don't want \part to use the plain page style, the correct way is to redefine \part not to use it. Or if you never want plain to show the page number redefine the plain page style. Or use  a class like scrrprt or memoir which has options for the part page style. Cheating with \pagenumbering{gobble} may look like an easy workaround but it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do it. Every page should have a number (maybe not printed).

Anyway, here's how you can do it. The main problem is avoiding duplicate anchors (which you ***always*** get with `\pagenumbering{gobble}` that should never be used).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{savepage}
\newcounter{savenopage}

\newcommand{\nonumbering}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\tocpagenumberfalse}%
  \setcounter{savepage}{\value{page}}%
  \pagenumbering{Alph}%
  \pagestyle{empty}%
  \setcounter{page}{\value{savenopage}}%
  #1%
  \clearpage
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\tocpagenumbertrue}%
  \pagestyle{plain}%
  \setcounter{savenopage}{\value{page}}%
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
  \setcounter{page}{\value{savepage}}%
}
\newif\iftocpagenumber
\tocpagenumbertrue

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\part}{plain}{empty}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\l@part}{#2}{\iftocpagenumber#2\fi}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\nopart}[1]{\part*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}}

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}

\begin{document}

\nonumbering{\tableofcontents}

\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}

\nonumbering{\nopart{Overture}}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\chapter{Chapter 0}

\nonumbering{\nopart{Part I}}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\chapter{Chapter 3}

\nonumbering{\nopart{Part II}}

\chapter{Chapter 4}

\chapter{Chapter 5}

\chapter{Chapter 6}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like this:

```latex
\documentclass[chapterprefix,sfdefaults=false]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}% Chapter 0 is ugly style.

\renewcommand{\partpagestyle}{empty}% change page style of part

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addchap{Preface}

\addpart{Overture}

\addchap{Introduction}

\chapter{Chapter 0}

\addpart{Part I}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
%\setcounter{page}{4}% would not do this

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\chapter{Chapter 3}

\addpart{Part II}

\chapter{Chapter 4}
%\setcounter{page}{7}% would not do this

\chapter{Chapter 5}

\chapter{Chapter 6}

\end{document}
```

And yes, the example counts the part pages although it does not show the page number. This avoids problems with destinations with the same identifier and problems with the page numbers of parts in the table of contents. A consistent page number helps the reader and also prevents problems for the writer.

However, if you want, you can do the fiddling with page numbers:

```latex
\documentclass[chapterprefix,sfdefaults=false]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}% Chapter 0 is ugly style.

\renewcommand{\partpagestyle}{empty}% change page style of part
\providecommand\gobble[1]{}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[pagenumberformat=\gobble]{tocline}{part}% don't show page numbers for part entries in ToC
\renewcommand*{\partheademptypage}{\addtocounter{page}{-1}\clearpage}% don't count part page; would not do this

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addchap{Preface}

\addpart{Overture}

\addchap{Introduction}

\chapter{Chapter 0}

\addpart{Part I}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\chapter{Chapter 3}

\addpart{Part II}

\chapter{Chapter 4}

\chapter{Chapter 5}

\chapter{Chapter 6}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{savedpagevalue} %This line defines a new counter named savedpagevalue. Counters in LaTeX are variables used for numbering, such as page numbers, chapter numbers, etc.

%This command defines a new command named pagevalue. When called, it saves the current page number plus one in the counter savedpagevalue.
\newcommand{\pagevalue}{
    \setcounter{savedpagevalue}{\value{page}}
    \stepcounter{savedpagevalue}
}
\makeatother

%This command defines a new command named stoppagenumbering. When called, it stops the page numbering by printing no page numbers. It also increments the savedpagevalue counter and starts a new page
\newcommand{\stoppagenumbering}{
    \pagevalue
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
}

%This command defines a new command named restartpagenumbering with one argument. When called with an argument specifying a page numbering style (such as arabic, Roman, etc.), it restarts the page numbering according to that style and sets the page number to the value stored in savedpagevalue.
\newcommand{\restartpagenumbering}[1]{
    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{#1}
    \setcounter{page}{\value{savedpagevalue}}
}

%This command defines a new command named blankpage. When called, it starts a new page, prints nothing on it (using \null), and suppresses any page numbering (using \thispagestyle{empty}).
\newcommand{\blankpage}{
    \newpage
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\tableofcontents


\chapter*{Preface}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}

\stoppagenumbering
\blankpage

\part*{Overture}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Overture}

\blankpage

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Chapter 0}
\stoppagenumbering

\blankpage

\part*{Part I}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part I}

\blankpage

\restartpagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\chapter{Chapter 3}

\stoppagenumbering

\blankpage

\part*{Part II}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part II}

\blankpage

\restartpagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Chapter 4}

\chapter{Chapter 5}

\chapter{Chapter 6}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you see egregs answer?

Comment: @Mensch I actually accepted it: pheraps you are asking if I wrote my answer inspired by egreg's one?

Comment: No, I asked because you are using gobble egreg asked not to use ...

Comment: @Mensch Oh, certainly: actually I didn't understand this point, even though UlrikeFischer tried to explain it. However, the code seems to work fine so I thought I'd share it: also looking at the logs there doesn't seem to be any warnings about using \pagenumbering{gobble}. However, I would like to point out that in my personal document I have implemented egreg's solution which is certainly safer than mine.